# How to setup different message post types in a database

Tags: database, database-design

I am building the feed for a news app.

I can do a ***single*** post containing 2 cards. There is an image card and there is a text card. I as the user, can create the post of the two cards in what ever order I want. After I do a post, other users can see my post containing the two cards in the order in which i posted them.

How do I set this up in the database? Here is what i have so far.

[image]
A user can do many posts, but what relationship do I put to show that the Post contains 2 objects in a particular order (BTW, in the real app, there are more than 2 message types). The Post can be in any combination. It can either contain 2 texts, or 2 images, or image and text, or text and image combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a new table called `post_items` - it will have 4 columns:

```
POST_ID - foreign key into table POST
ITEM_TYPE_ID - ENUM, determining which table the column ITEM_ID is foreign key into
ITEM_ID - foreign key into either TextPost, ImagePost or any other desired table
ITEM_ORDER - defines the order of the item inside the post
```